# Detect collision between two 2D kinematics bodies godot

Tags: game-development, godot

I'm doing a very simple 2D platform game project, you can see here how it is so far: https://master.d3kjckivyd1c76.amplifyapp.com/src/Games/PlatformGame2D101/index.html

But I can't detect the collision between the enemy (the chainsaw) and the player.

I have this code to detect if the two bodies are colliding, but it only prints the `Enemy` when the player is moving:

```py
func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
  velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)

  for i in get_slide_count():
    var collision = get_slide_collision(i)
    if collision.collider.is_in_group("Enemy"): print("Enemy")
```

- [original file](https://bitbucket.org/201flaviosilva-labs/platform-game-2d-101-godot/src/697335074bca6ddc08a7712b1d7963de271398b9/Project/Scripts/Player.gd#lines-34)
- [I uploaded the project to the Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/201flaviosilva-labs/platform-game-2d-101-godot/src/master/)

Thanks any help : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/yojmz8/detect_collision_between_two_2d_kinematics_bodies/

But basically the player, it’s not moving, so it's not colliding

Here it's the changes that I made to fix: https://bitbucket.org/201flaviosilva-labs/platform-game-2d-101-godot/commits/61e37823eb9758fdafd222f2cdecf3e0668a3808

Answer (score 0):

I did plenty of 2d games using pygame and i used this two.

1. You can use sprite.spritecollideany() which takes 2 arguments. The sprite u want to collide, in your case the chainsaw with another group of sprites. this requires a loop, which will look like this:

   ```
    for swordman in swordsmen1_army:
    # Swordsman1 attackin Swordsman2
    colliding_sword2 = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(swordman, swordsmen2_army)
    if colliding_sword2:
        swordman.attacking = True
        swordman.unleash = False
        if swordman.index == 3:
            colliding_sword2.health -= SWORD_HIT
   ```
2. If you want to collide just two sprites you can use  pygame.Rect.colliderect() which checks for detection of 2 sprites with each other. This one requires no loop and looks like this:

   ```
    if pygame.Rect.colliderect(ball.rect, border1.rect):
    ball.down_collision = True
    ball_y_speed *= -1
   ```

Both of them will return a boolean value and from there, you can use an if statement and continue with the code.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the help, but that's not quite what I'm looking for, godot and pygame are not quite the same thing, and they don't have the same methods :)